# "Ask/answer early, often"?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by another question: ["Vote early, vote often"](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/79) ... 
What's the strategy for (private) beta:

1. Should we try to populate the site with as many example questions and answers?
2. Should we focus on quality over quantity?

Comment: For 2.: quality over quantity, of course. Crap begets crap ("broken windows" and all that.); at this stage, I'm thinking it shouldn't be too hard for the experts hanging around here to come up with the questions they're usually asked. We can seed the site with those.

Comment: @J.M.: That should be an answer :)

Comment: @Colin: Once I figure how I feel about 1., I'll write an answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

We definitely want to populate the site as much as possible, but I think we should avoid posting questions simply to provide filler. In particular, don't ask questions to which you know the answer as a sort of "example."

We also want this site to be oriented towards experts so, while in the long run we may tolerate *some* amateurish questions, we are focused right now on the expert community. This means that the questions and answers in the beginning **must** be of high quality to set a good example and build a community of experts.

So in brief, **ask as many questions as possible, but only if they are good questions.**