# How do we encourage people to vote?

Tags: discussion, voting

I really like the post ["Vote early, vote often"](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/vote-early-vote-often). When I look at the [all-time voting statistics](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all), it seems like our experienced users, as a group, don't vote much (between a vote or two per day of membership, maybe less). Is this level of participation normal? If not, how can we encourage people to vote?

Comment: Voting more might also encourage new people to continue participating, as they get positive feedback from a reputation increase.

Comment: my personal policy for voting over at cstheory.SE is to vote on every question I read and understand.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: That's my theory also.

Answer (score 4):

The thing that's really holding me back is the relatively low rate of questions being asked, and I think the thing keeping vote totals low overall is the relative smallness of the community. The monthly voting statistics for [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=month) and [computational science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=month) look similar, but the scicomp.SE community is much smaller, which means we have fewer frequent voters, and fewer voters period.

Ultimately, I think we just need to [attract more people to the site](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/71/81).

Comment: I have the same reason. On math.SE, I easily expend my 30-40 day voting allowance simply because there are a number of questions and answers that pop up per day. Here, I've seen at least two day where nothing new came up. More people would probably get their "Suffrage" and "Vox Populi" if only there was more stuff to vote on...